# Removing new lines and escape characters introduced when reading file in PHP

Tags: php, escaping

```
{
  "elements": [
    {
      "cardtype": "textcard",
      "title": "Final Fantasy",
      "titlesize": "medium"
    }
  ]
}
```

The above is content of a file. I want to return this in response. I use file_get_contents to read the contents, however, I get this:

```
{\n  \"elements\": [\n    {\n      \"cardtype\": \"textcard\",\n      \"title\": \"Final Fantasy\",\n      \"titlesize\": \"medium\",\n ...
```

The new lines and escaping is not what I want. Is there some way to avoid that?

Comment: Are you creating this file or reading it from an external source?

Comment: This file is present, but has new lines etc in it.

Answer (score 0):

use following code for removing `\n` from you data.
`$fileData = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', file_get_contents($fileName));`

Comment: and how to get rid of escaped characters?

Comment: use [`stripslashes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) for escaping character.

Comment: sorry mate, its working, I used json_encode after all this!

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of escape characters use [stripslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php).
To get rid of \n use [str_replace()](http://php.net/str_replace).

```
<?php

    $string = file_get_contents("file.txt");
    $string = str_replace("\n", "", $string);
    $string = stripslashes($string);

?>
```

**UPDATE:**

Try this.

```
    $string = file_get_contents("file.txt");
    $string = str_replace("\n", "", $string);
    $string = str_replace("\\", "", $string);
```

Comment: If you open the file in Notepad (or similar program), can you see the escape characters and "\n" in it?

Comment: So the \n is removed, but escaped characters remain. I believe its something to do with magic quotes?

Comment: That doesn't feel right, does it? Unescaping also means replacing \\ with \, wont that be missed in this? BTW, why is stripslashes not working, any case when it can behave erratic?

Comment: that doesnt work either. Can you check if it works for you?

Comment: got it working Emil, sorry, I was using another json_encode after all of these!